# how i replace id with date in json using object.keys, spred operator, and if condition

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, object

my json (compact version for better reading)

```
{
    "currency":{
       "symbol":"$",
       "code":"USD"
    },
    "prices":{
       "data":{        
          "2022-05-01":{
             "property":{
                "expectedroomssold_adjusted":6.34,
                "exproomssold_l1":3.82
             },
             "12157":{
                "error":false,
                "price":7,
                "original_price":150.0,
                "suggested_price":7,
             }
          }
}
```

please tell me the code for replace the date with id in react

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new object and copy all properties of JSON in this object with all properties of date in id and delete the date property from the object

**Example**

```js
const json = {
  a: 5,
  b: 7,
  "2022-05-22": {
    a: 5,
    b: 7,
  }
};
const id = '2';
const date = "2022-05-22";
const newObj = {
  ...json,
  [id]: {
    ...json[date]
  }
};
delete newObj[date];
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: i don't want yo delete any object, i just want to swap it. using object.keys, spread operator and map in app.js file.

Comment: `delete newObj[date];` does not delete any object , it delete property specified from object 
**Example**
delete obj.a // delete property a from obj